# ffmpeg duplicates image overlay (place it twice to the output)

Tags: ffmpeg

I need gif overlay (equaliser line) on png background and mix it with audio to video output.

Last problem is, that gif overlay is placed twice to the output video. One on 0:0 coordinates and second on 50:262 which is specified in the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IApYx.png) overlay. 
Similary as attached [image]

`ffmpeg -i "audio.mp3" -ignore_loop 0 -i "anim-eq.gif" -loop 1 -i "bg.png" -filter_complex "[2]scale=w=1080:h=608,overlay=0:0[vt]; [1]scale=w=350:h=84,[vt]overlay=50:262" -c:a aac -ab 64k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -c:v libx264 -shortest "output.mp4"`

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set two overlay filters. There should be only one.

```
-filter_complex "[2]scale=w=1080:h=608[vt];[1]scale=w=350:h=84[eq];[vt][eq]overlay=50:262"
```